# Error updating TextView from TimerTask's run method

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to test UI and Timer class possibilities. So I tried the following exercise:

=== TestTimerActivity.java ===

```
package com.tvt.TestTimer;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;


public class TestTimerActivity extends Activity {
    TextView _tv;
    Timer _t;
    int _count = 0;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        //

//        _tv = (TextView) getWindow().getDecorView().findViewById( R.id.TextViewTime );

        _tv = (TextView) findViewById( R.id.TextViewTime );

        UpdateTime(); // Completes OK

        _t = new Timer();

        _t.scheduleAtFixedRate( new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                _count++;
                UpdateTime(); // Fails
            }
        }, 1000, 1000 );
    }

    protected void UpdateTime() {
        _tv.setText( "" + _count );
    }
}
```

=== TestTimerActivity.java ===

=== main.xml ===

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
<TextView  
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:gravity="center_horizontal" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_gravity="center" android:text="@string/header" android:id="@+id/TestViewHeader" android:textStyle="bold"/>
<TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/TextViewTime" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" android:gravity="center_horizontal" android:text="-"></TextView>
</LinearLayout>
```

=== main.xml ===

The very first UpdateTime call (from onCreate) completes OK but the same call from TimerTask::run() fails giving the message "TestTimer class has stopped unexpectedly".

Any idea? Where is my fault?

--
SY, TVT

Answer (score 11):

Do that UpateTime() operation on the UI thread.

```
protected void UpdateTime() 
{
     runOnUiThread(new Runnable() 
     {
    public void run() 
    {
            _tv.setText( "" + _count );
        }
     });
}
```

Hopefully resolves your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Updating the UI from a thread other than the UI/main thread will fail as Android does not allow it. Try using a [Handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) to post messages back to the UI thread.

Or maybe try using [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) which presents a set of really simple callback methods to handle the worker and UI threads. But that might not be exactly what you need since you're trying to test out the TimerTask class.

Comment: **Thanks a lot**, _guys_! I'll try it! I'm a C++ developer and it turns out that it's not very easy to find systematic Android development guide. Is there any?

Comment: @Fileaholic : From personal experience, it might be a good idea to get comfortable with Java first, and then move on to working with Android. Once you have that down, pick a goal and go ahead and build it, figuring out whatever you need along the way. It's just simpler to learn that way, esp because you'll make plenty of mistakes, and you will learn how to work with Android better that way.