# set map in google maps with TimerTask

Tags: android, maps, location

I would like to change the Position of the map in google maps v2

But Ive done it in a TimerTask ... target, zoom, bearing and so on and it says

"IllegalStateException - not on the main thread

What should I do? Any help?

```
class Task extends TimerTask { 

    @Override 
    public void run() {
        CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
                .target(Zt)      // Sets the center of the map to Mountain View
                .zoom(12)                   // Sets the zoom
                .bearing(180)                // Sets the orientation of the camera to east
                .tilt(30)                   // Sets the tilt of the camera to 30 degrees
                .build();                   // Creates a CameraPosition from the builder

        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
    }
}

Timer timer = new Timer();

timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Task(), 0, 20000);
```

Comment: You can't update the user interface outside the main/ui thread. This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7010951/error-updating-textview-from-timertasks-run-method

Answer (score 0):

The timer task runs on a different thread than the UI thread. In Android, you are not allowed to perform UI operation from a non-UI thread. Use `runOnUiThread` method to send operations to the UI thread:

```
class Task extends TimerTask { 

    @Override 
    public void run() {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override 
            public void run() {
                CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
                        .target(Zt)      // Sets the center of the map to Mountain View
                        .zoom(12)                   // Sets the zoom
                        .bearing(180)                // Sets the orientation of the camera to east
                        .tilt(30)                   // Sets the tilt of the camera to 30 degrees
                        .build();                   // Creates a CameraPosition from the builder

                mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
            }
        });
    }
}

Timer timer = new Timer();

timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Task(), 0, 20000);
```